# How do I create (master) users for phpmyAdmin installed as package with Synology

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, synology

Probably the dumbest question ever but apparently I don't see a button anywhere to create a master user in a new phpmyadmin installation via package center Synology...
I need to create a database for a Joomla installation on Synology.

I got the Welcome to phpMyAdmin window but whatever I enter for user/password I receive an error. My server choice is MariaDB 10:

Cannot login to my MySQL Server
Mysqli_real_connect(): (HYooo/1045): Access denied for 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Sorry for my ignornace but looking forward to your solution or suggestions...
Richard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cx2a.jpg)

Comment: phpMyAdmin uses the MySQL user. It doesn't have its own users. When installing MariaDB you should be able to create a new master account.

Comment: No... sorry.... MariaDB 10 was successfully installed...

Comment: @Richard If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.